# Trigger a Form event from inside another event

Tags: c#, forms

How can I trigger a form click event from inside another event? I made a label that covers a drop-down menu (combo box) and I want to trigger that drop down menu when the label is clicked. So, clicking the label makes the drop-down menu actually drop down. Right now, I have created the label click event, but I am not sure what I need to call from the ComboBox "Settings" object to make the menu actually drop down.

```
private void settingsLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Click // I think this is what needs to be called but how do I trigger it?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i'm not mistaken comboBox of you have Name is Settings, then it will look like this:

```
private void settingsLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Settings.DroppedDown = true;
}
```